# How to increase icon's stroke thickness using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, stroke

I'm using Google's Material Design icons in my project. My aim is to increase the thickness of the menu icon's strokes (see under the navigation section). How can I do this using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)?

So far, I've tried going to Fill and Stroke and then adjusting the width but that seems to have no effect.

Please note I'm a novice at graphic design.

**Ref:** https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/

Comment: Can you please add the image here by editing your question? Suppose the given link is broken ... BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Hi @Kurt, thanks for the welcome :)
The image is .svg format and when I try to edit my question and upload it, it tells me it's an unsupported format.

Comment: You can change the format to jpg or png and add it. Theese are supported ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we can't apply a different stroke width to many stock icons such as the ones in the question is that they are not made of strokes but filled objects instead. This can be visualized by switching to path mode in Inkscape:

[image]

[image]

In the icon objects neither stroke nor fill is defined, making them more versatile for web customization.

To make the stroke wider we therefore first need to define a stroke and a stroke color in *Object > Fill and Stroke* properties. After that we can increase stroke width in the *Stroke style* tab.

To widen a stroke in a single object of the icon we may break apart the path <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to then select the resulting sub-object:

[image]

After adding a stroke color black, and increasing the stroke width we will obtain a thicker arrow in above example:

[image]

Note that this will **not** change the object's geometry but the stroke thickness is added in addition.

To change an object's color we may define a fill, and the desired fill color similarly:

[image]

Comment: I'm a newbie on it, but how about inset and outset: Ctrl + ), Ctrl + ( and Ctrl + J?

Comment: @RafaelXavier as a total noob in this stuff, who just wanted to do this for a presentation, the Ctrl + ( tip proved golden. In my opinion you should post this as the answer as it is exactly what is needed.